# Python web scraping: how to ignore children elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-3.6

[Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pl104.png)

I am trying to get a text from the 2nd "p class="text-muted""

Generally I use:

```
outline = soup.find_all("p", {"class":"text-muted"})

for item in outline:
    print (item.text)
```

or

```
print (item.contents[3].text)
```

1, 2, 3 in whichever I can find what I'm looking for. But there are 2 "class":"text-muted" now. First code prints everything in the element with its children and the text I want. Also when I add `.contents[0]` or 1, 2, 10, ... I'm getting `IndexError: list index out of range`.

How do I print only the text I want directly in `<"p", {"class":"text-muted">` and just ignore all the children?

Answer (score 1):

```
soup.find_all("p",{"class":"text-muted"},text=True,recursive=False)
```

It returns the text value for that child only and does not consider child elements.